# Custom Field XSL -- Name vs FieldType

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, custom-field-types

I've created a custom field according to the following walkthrough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx

My field XML is as follows:

```
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">ReviewStatus</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">Choice</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">Review Status</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">Review Status</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">MyFields.MyReviewStatusField, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Field>
  </FieldType>
```

and my XSL is as follows:

```
  <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='ReviewStatus']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="." />
    <span style="background-color:lightgreen;font-weight:bold">
      <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="$thisNode/@*"/> -->
      <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]"/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template >
```

Now my issue is this,  if I deploy my custom field to the server, and add a column of this type to a list, SharePoint gives me the opportunity to give it a "Name" so perhaps I name it simply "Status".  After some debugging I found the problem with this is that my XSL does not match because the "Name" is "Status" and not the TypeName "ReviewStatus" as I have programmed into my XML and my transform.

What is the proper way to ensure that my transform matches and give users the ability to change the field "Name"?  Do I override SPField InternalName?  What is the best way?

EDIT:  I found an attribute @FieldType that I can use instead of @Name, it appears to behave as I want (so the match looks like this):

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@FieldType='ReviewStatus']" mode="body">
```

How can I see all of the attributes on the FieldRef?  I've tried the following but saw neither Name or FieldType in the result (I assume I need to tweak this slightly):

```
 <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@FieldType='ReviewStatus']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="." />
    <span style="background-color:lightgreen;font-weight:bold">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$thisNode/@*"/>          
    </span>
  </xsl:template >

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>=<xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to [customize the Rendering of a Field on a List View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx) the following match attributes in templates are commonly used:

> FieldRef[@Name='#FieldInternalName#']
>   FieldRef[@ID='#FieldID#']

So, in your case instead of Field Internal Name (`@Name`) you could specify match attribute for Field ID, like

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@ID='5a14d1ab-1513-48c7-97b3-657a5ba6c742']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="." />
    <span style="background-color:lightgreen;font-weight:bold">
      <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="$thisNode/@*"/> -->
      <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]"/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template >
```

> Note: Specify your field ID for match attribute

---

FieldRef Element description may be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543225.aspx)

Hope this helps,

Vadim

Comment: This answer helped me alot.  Here is my own thread: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74255/xslt-template-to-match-multiple-fieldrefs/74267#74267 and here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058776/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-currently-matched-xsl-node-into-a-variable  Thank you very much!