# XSLT Template to Match Multiple FieldRefs

Tags: xslt

How can I match on multiple fieldrefs?

I've made a copy of `fldtypes.xsl` in the `/_layouts/xsl/` directory where I can work with fields in my lists (I have to restart the web application to get it to take).

Now, I have this routine which will convert the text in a field into an icon by changing the display value of the field by adding some custom css classes (that supply the icons).

My problem is that I want to use this same template on more than one field ref.  This one will run on any column in my portal with the title of `Yes or No Column`, but I want it to match *also* on another column entitled `Approval`.

```
    <!-- Convert the Fields into a status icons    -->  
    <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='Yes or No Column']" mode="body">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@Yes_x0020_or_x0020_No_x0020_Column" />
        <xsl:variable name="yes">Yes</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="no">No</xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $yes)">
                <span class="yesno yes"></span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $no)">
                <span class="yesno no"></span>
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <span><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
            </xsl:otherwise>                    
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

So how can I use the same template on mutliple fieldrefs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was actually simple to get the match on two different fields:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='YesNo1']|FieldRef[@Name='YesNo2']" mode="body">
```

You just separate the elements with a '|' and still use the `FieldRef`.

That's it.

For choice fields, the mode will always be `body`, by the way.

**[edit]**

Ha ha - I asked a [similar question in Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057312/how-to-match-this-or-that-in-an-xsl-template?rq=1) and forgot about it.  Well, now the answer is in Sharepoint Stack Exchange, too.

In order to fetch the value of the current field into a variable, do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
```

*There are [some other examples of how to match multiple fields here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057312/how-to-match-this-or-that-in-an-xsl-template?rq=1).*

Also, since it is related, if you need to test multiple values (and you are using `<xsl:choose>` - you can do use both `and` and `or` in the test!

```
<xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, 'false') and contains($currentValue,'no'">
    <!--do something-->
</xsl:when>
```

or:

```
<xsl:when test="$currentValue='Yes' or $currentValue='yes' or $currentValue='True' or $currentValue='true' ">
    <!--do something-->
</xsl:when>
```